# Java overwriting file in process

Tags: java, openssl, overwrite

I am trying to overwrite a file in Java. The problem is the overwriting is done within an OpenSSl process.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
         try {
            rt.exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c","openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -in \"" + source.getAbsolutePath()+
                    "\" -out \"" + source.getAbsolutePath()+".enc\""  + " -p -pass pass:" + Key});

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Why the -out parameter does not get overwritten? When I execute the same exact code in cmd.exe it does overwrite it.

Comment: Are spaces being inserted between the command, option switches, and parameters?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that an error is occurring but not being displayed. Try displaying the output of the `ErrorStream`:

```
Process process = rt.exec(...);

BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
String errorLine = null;
while ((errorLine = error.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.print(errorLine);
}
```

Also add this to verify they the array is what you think it should be:

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c","openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -in \"" + source.getAbsolutePath()+
                    "\" -out \"" + source.getAbsolutePath()+".enc\""  + " -p -pass pass:" + Key}));
```

Comment: There is no error to be displayed I.E. the while loop gets skipped.

Comment: Does the `InputStream` display anything?

Comment: I get java.io.FileInputStream@5bda13

Comment: No. That is the Object itself. you need to just replace the `getErrorStream` bit above with `getInputStream` to see the output

Comment: Initially I got a key and IV which is expected and is exactly what cmd spits out. But when I run it again I get nothing thus meaning it does not overwrite?

Comment: Use 2 loops one for the `InputStream` another for the `ErrorStream` and see if any errors are produced the 2nd time its run

Comment: In one instance it displayed the kev and IV and did overwrite. In other instances I got a "< was unexpected this time" and it did not overwrite. Also, in one run nothing was displayed.

Comment: Upon further runs I also get "The system cannot find the specified file"

Comment: For some reason, only on this project, console printing does not display and I've had to use JOptionPane...any ideas?

Comment: [cmd.exe, /c, openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -in "D:\My Documents\internEncrypt\OPEN_TTT.txt" -out "D:\My Documents\internEncrypt\OPEN_TTT.txt.enc" -p -pass pass:717;H33BHA15]

Comment: It seems I get the "System cannot find the specified file" error ONLY when my key contains the '<' and '>' characters. This is verified in both my application and the command prompt